# How to only allow implementations of an interface in the same package

Tags: java, interface, package, visibility, multiple-inheritance

I have a package `P` with

- `public interface I`
- `public class S1 extends Foo implements I`
- `public class S2 extends Bar implements I`.

Now I want to forbid implementations of `I` outside of `P`, but `I` should be public, since I use it for a `public method(I parameter)`.

How can this be done?

Is there some "package-final pattern" for this?

Did you ever have such a situation?

---

Details:

I'm aware of the possibility of using an abstract class with only package private constructors instead of interface `I`, but `S1` and `S2` extend different classes, so I would need multiple inheritance (since simulated multiple inheritance (see e.g. Effective Java item 18) does not work here).

Comment: If you don't need the interface outside the package you could just make the interface package scope: interface I, rather than public interface I.

Comment: @karakuricoder: I need the interface outside the package (see my comment for Ian Armit's answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could also try the following attempt:

Use a dummy package private interface and create a method in your public interface which returns it. Like this:

```
public interface I {
  Dummy getDummy(); // this can only be used and implemented inside of the 
                    // current package, because Dummy is package private
  String methodToUseOutsideOfPackage();
}

interface Dummy {}
```

Thanks to this, only classes from the current package will be able to implement interface `I`. All classes from outside will never be able to implement the method `Dummy getDummy()`. At the same time the classes from outside of the package will be able to use all other methods of the interface `I` which do not have the `Dummy` interface in their signature.

This solution isn't beautiful, because you have one useless method in your interface `I`, but you should be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: I would like to point out that if some class A implements the interface I, then A can be extended by some class B outside the I package. (B is then an implementation of I outside the package of I). To prevent this, any class implementing I (such as A) should be declared final or have a constructor with a package visibility.

Answer (score 4):

Can't do it. If your interface is `public` it can be implemented by anyone. Is it possible for your two implementations to extend an abstract class and encapsulate the ones they are currently extending?

Better question is do you REALLY need to enforce this rule. The point of an interface is that you should be able to accept and implementation of the interface. If you really need to, you could do the validation at the point of use of the interface by checking that the class fo the instance is one of the two that you allow.

Comment: other languages do have vaguely similar facilities. For example, C# has the access modifier `internal` that makes an interface available only within an _assembly_.

Comment: as others have pointed out, default scope is package private but since the OP lists the interface as `public` I assumed that the interface needed to be referenced from outside the package (as is confirmed by the OP's comment)

Comment: @John: +1 for the answer, although I had hoped for a better solution. Currently I am doing sth. like you suggested: checking dynamically with `this.getClass().getPackage()!= paraeter.getClass().getPackage())`, so I can extend `I` within the package without having to update the checking.

Comment: Yeah, I feel you but I think you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the interface delcaration

```
interface I
```

it should make it only accessible from the package and class

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: I wouldn't be able to have `public method(I parameter)` then (hence -1).